# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException throws while Thread is working normally

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception, android-thread

I'm using Thread to set color to a list of `ImageView` one by one after time of `Thread.sleep`. It works normally but after few loops of `Thread`, my app is stop working and throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        int position = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                if (position >= MAX_ITEM) {
                    position = 0;
                }
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        for (int i = 0; i < itemIndicators.size(); i++) {
                            itemIndicators.get(i).setSelected(false);
                        }
                        if (position >= 0){
                            itemIndicators.get(position-1).setSelected(true);
                        }
                    }
                });

                position++;

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    };
```

My list's size is the same number to MAX_ITEM.
Please help me out of this. Thanks so much!

Comment: Are you sure itemIndicators is size MAX_ITEM?  You really should be using itemIndicators.size() instead.  And make sure itemIndicators is something that can be accessed asycnhronously safely.

Comment: yeah, I will keep your words for the next time. Thank you so much for helping xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your error is caused by this line

```
  if (position >= 0){
     itemIndicators.get(position-1).setSelected(true);
   }
```

you should edit your condition to `position > 0` to avoid getting `get(-1)`

Answer (score 1):

If position is 0 you're accessing item at index -1

```
if (position >= 0) {
    itemIndicators.get(position-1).setSelected(true);
}
```

Remove the -1.